# What is the numerical definition of a Satoshi relative to a BTC?

Tags: satoshi, divisibility

In previous definitions of a Satoshi, I only saw the decimal place in front of the 0's and the #1 (.0001), but no 0's after the #1 and that's confusing to me. If however you also put the 0's behind the #1 it makes much more sense to me: Ex. .0000100000 BTC = 100,000.00 Satoshis. I can now see the number value of Satoshi based on the number of 0's behind the #1!

1BTC = 100,000,000.00 Satoshi, is this a accurate understanding?

Answer (score 4):

Satoshis are indivisible on the Bitcoin blockchain. Therefore, it doesn't make any sense to add a decimal point or digits after the decimal point to satoshi values.

The conversion is:

100,000,000 satoshi = 1 BTC

or

1 satoshi = 0.00000001 BTC

Comment: I'm trying to visualize where the numerical value is actually fully represented & think I see it now. If you include the 0 which comes before the decimal point then the numerical value makes sense, but only then. 0.001 = 1000 Setoshi, 0.0001 = 10,000 Setoshi & 0.00012345 is 12,345 Satoshi etc., correct?

Comment: "0.001 = 1000 Setoshi" is incorrect. 0.001 BTC are 100000 satoshis.

Comment: Murch, I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question, but I'm not confident i understand how to read the Satoshi numbers. Please clarify: Lets try again, please. Obviously I get this much, 100,000,000 Satoshi = 1BTC, therefore, there are presently being used a total of 9 digits including the 0 left of the decimal = 0.12345678, which would make 0.12345678 BTC= 12,345,678 Satoshi. Is this-Correct or not correct? If that's not correct please give more than one example, something like what I've done using numbers other than 1 and 0. Thank you Murch.

Comment: Yes that's correct. However, in your example with 0.001 BTC the 1 would be on position 3 out of the 0.12345678, so there would be five zeros following not three as you wrote.